# Process finished with exit code -1073740791 (0xC0000409)

Tags: java, intellij-idea, javafx, scenebuilder

I am writing Java code with JavaFX and Scenebuilder on Intellij, and I tried compiling and it gave me this error:

> Process finished with exit code -1073740791 (0xC0000409)

I tried scanning my disk for corrupt files, I tried running my program on a different computer (my code worked). I even tried compiling and running code I knew had worked a few days prior - still didn't work. The only thing I have found is that it isn't code, and it has to do with some process, because, when I compiled in safe mode, it worked perfectly fine.
Please help, I need this for my school
Thank you!

Comment: See linked question - it's a bug in nVidia driver. Try reverting to a previous version (although at this point there may be a fixed newer version available from nVidia).